# Error In import image Link?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I had imported a csv file to add bulk products in magento. i had mentioned Image , small image and thumbnail as a link **"www.mylink.com/imagename.jpg"** . .

after the importing has done the image is not appearing in my frontend. .

the image link is appear in the alt and not in SRC. .

**For example**

so kindly help me out to mention it in SRC. . .

[image: This Is My Doubt]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, I assume you have your images in your server/local system itself. If that's the case then it is not a good way to import images like that (by url of the same system) and it is also not correct(SEO wise) to put urls in "alt" tags of images. If the images are in the same system as your site then you have to provide only media(after media/import/) path to images in csv like "/imagename.jpg".

And the other scenario in which you want to import images from external url(from external resources) then you may have to override(not modify) core code as in below link:

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/

Also for importing images from url, refer below links too:

<strike>http://www.forums.moderndignity.com/threads/import-magento-product-images-form-external-urls-magento-1-7-0.1789/</strike>

http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html